# Code coverage mismatched while 2gp packaging

Tags: managed-package, code-coverage, appexchange, unlocked-package, second-generation-packaging

I am currently trying to deploy my final release package but error stats that i don't have minimum code coverage to promote package.

[image]

But when I create scratch org and run all test I could see no class has below 85%

[image]

Let me know how to find which component has how much coverage after packaging?

Comment: Are you creating the package version with code coverage and validation flag enabled before promoting it?

Comment: @mqnjith yes i m doing with - - codecoverage check, also to let you know that I have total of 5 packages in which only one of them has got this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that code coverage was calculated on test class present inside particular package dependent package test coverage was not considered while packaging.